# Can pfSense do routing or port forwarding based on DNS name?

Tags: routing, proxy, pfsense-2

Currently our network looks like this:

[image]

The issue is that `OpenVPN Access Server` does [not support working behind a proxy server](https://serverfault.com/questions/1041848/is-there-a-way-to-get-pre-configured-openvpn-as-connect-client-server-locked-pr) so some features are currently not working. As we only have 1 external IP and we have no possibilities to add some extra, i try to find a way to get `OpenVPN AS` working and hosting some website's (on other servers) at the same time.

I was thinking, maybe i can "route" traffic to vpn.company.com (443) directly from pfSense (dns based port forwarding or something???) to the `OpenVPN AS` and all other traffic (port 443) to the `Nginx proxy` server. This would make the network looking like this:

[image]

This way, the `OpenVPN AS` is not behind a proxy server anymore and can work like a direct port forwarding. The other website's still work like they currently do.

1. Is it possible to do some routing, based on a (external) domain at
   all? (with other words can my idea work?)
2. If 1. is answered with yes, is it possible with pfSense? if yes, how?

I tried to Google this and found a lot of stuff but nothing that could help me. Orriginialy I'm a software engineer and no network engineer so apologize if i ask something stupid.

Comment: DNS is an application-layer thing, and the network and transport protocols use addresses, not names. Anything at or below OSI layer-4 has no concept of names or DNS, only addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS-based port forwarding isn't a thing. The transport layer has no idea about DNS names. The only way to do something like that is with an application-layer (aware) proxy and, of course, an application-layer protocol that uses host names, like HTTP.

With just a single IP address, you'll need a dedicated TCP port for OpenVPN (and probably one for UDP, too). Forwarding that to the AS should be no problem on the pfSense. You can change OpenVPN's TCP or UDP ports during installation or afterwards: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/advanced-option-settings-on-the-command-line/

Another approach would be *policy-based* forwarding, depending on the source address of an external packet. That way, you could theoretically forward known VPN clients to the OVPN AS and the rest of the Internet to your web servers. I don't think that's practical, however.

Comment: `With just a single IP address, you'll need a dedicated TCP port for OpenVPN (and probably one for UDP, too). Forwarding that to the AS should be no problem on the pfSense.` - For the `OpenVPN Access Server` is this no option as it requires port 443 like my (https) website's. So actually i need a proxy which is not supported so i can throw this idea away. Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: You can very easily run an OpenVPN AS on an alternative port, I'm doing that myself.